# Ruby- get date from microseconds

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, history

Alright I was looking at this in python but I just like ruby better. What I'm trying to do is get a date and time from this number - 12988822998637849 - which is the number of microseconds since January 1, 1601 UTC. This is how Chrome stores it's timestamps and i've seen a number of methods to do this in python, but I am just more comfortable with ruby and I have no idea on how to even start going about doing this. (My Google-Fu didn't help me this time)
Note this example number is from a few days ago. I'll take any help I can get. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look at [**Time.at**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-c-at).

A Windows file time is "a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)." [Ref.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime.aspx)

In contrast, Ruby stores times like Unix: "Time is stored internally as the number of seconds and microseconds since the epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC" [Ref.](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_time.html)

```
# This return a Time
Time.at(12988822998637849/1000000-11644473600) # Epoch Diff is 11644473600
# => 2012-08-07 11:23:18 -0300 

# This returns a String
Time.at(12988822998637849/1000000-11644473600).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M.%S")
# => "2012-08-07 11:23.18"
```

Comment: I think you may have too many zeroes in your "seconds to microseconds" conversion...

Comment: Sorry, It was and old edit that I copy-pasted...Now it's correct!

Comment: Perfect. So helpful. Thank you!! just need to figure out this timezone stuff and i'm in business

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to create a Ruby date using the Chrome time origin, then increment by the requisite number of microseconds:

```
Time.gm(1601,1,1) + 12988822998637849 / 1000000

# => 2012-08-07 14:23:18 UTC
```